# how to use kmlviewer to implement kml with ground image overlay?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

hi im completely new to objective-c and xcode , ive tried a few kml files with the kmlviewer samplecode that is in the apple developer website it all works but when i try one kml sample file with an ground overlay an image overlay on the google map it doesnt work , is the kmlviewer suppose to work with every kml file or for certain kml files only ? where can i find a tutorial to implement a ground image overlay kml file in xcode 
any help will be really appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer in [Getting xml data in DetailView from a map view (Iphone IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351841/getting-xml-data-in-detailview-from-a-map-view-iphone-ios/5410285#5410285). I did som research on the sample app for the question and the XML parser in the example app does not parse alot.

If you want a ground overlay you'll have to improve the `KMLParser` first and then start the drawing.